# Problems while creating a class inside of a class

Tags: python, class, oop

I was messing around with classes in python and I was wondering if it's possible to create a class inside of a class. Unfortunatly I found out that I can't refer to the main class properties inside of a subclass or get data between subclasses
Here is an example:

```
class Example:
    class Colors:
        RED = (255, 0, 0)
        GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
        BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
        YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
        BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

    class Shapes:
        rectangle = Example.Colors.RED
        square = Example.Colors.BLUE
        circle = Example.Colors.YELLOW

print(Example.Shapes.rectangle)
print(Example.Shapes.square)
print(Example.Shapes.circle)
```

But when I run the code there is a name error where Example is not defined. Is there a different way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the nested code being a class. It's not possible to use `Example.Colors.RED` - *or even `Example.Colors`* - inside the definition of `Example`; it's *not because* `Colors` is a class, but because the name `Example` hasn't been assigned yet.

Comment: Nested class definitions are more trouble than they’re worth IMO.  Use modules to organize your classes rather than trying to turn classes into modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top-level class name is not available in the global namespace until the top-level definition is complete. Since the references from the nested class are not inside methods, it attempts to evaluate them as the nested class is being defined, which leads to the error.

I've run into this problem before, and I solved it by using a class method to complete the initialization of the class.  For example, the following works:

```
class Example:
    class Colors:
        RED = (255, 0, 0)
        GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
        BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
        YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
        BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

    class Shapes:
        @classmethod
        def complete_class(cls, cls2):
            cls.rectangle = cls2.RED
            cls.square = cls2.BLUE
            cls.circle = cls2.YELLOW

    Shapes.complete_class(Colors)

print(Example.Shapes.rectangle)
print(Example.Shapes.square)
print(Example.Shapes.circle)
```

Note that no class instances are created.  All of the initialization is done on the classes themselves.